# Generate Sexy Primes

Tags: code-golf, math, primes

[Sexy Primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexy_prime) are pairs of numbers \$(n, n+6)\$ such as \$n\$ and \$n+6\$ are both prime

You need to create a function which will take an integer, check for sexy primes from 0 to that integer, and return an array of arrays.

For example, `listSexy(30)` must return `[[5,11], [7,13], [11,17], [13,19], [17,23], [23,29]]` or some equivalent.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the program with the shortest bytecount wins!

Comment: Can you explain what the desired output format looks like?

Comment: Bah, I hate it when the challenge changes after answers have been submitted.

Comment: Is there a certain reason to check from 0? Why shouldn't I check from (5,11)? A short definition of sexy primes should be given right here, while linking to Wikipedia for further reading is welcome.

Comment: In Portuguese Sexy Primes translates to the same as Sexy Cousins!

Comment: @sergiol haha...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## MATLAB 32

```
i=1:n;i(isprime(i)&isprime(i+6))
```

n is your number

Comment: +1 That is the right tool for the job: `isprime`. Not that the op intended it.

Comment: This could  be shortened by giving the `isprime` function a shorter name: `i=1:n;p=@isprime;i(p(i)&p(i+6))`

Answer (score 6):

### J, <strike>34</strike> <strike>33</strike> <strike>31</strike> <strike>32</strike> <strike>39</strike> 37 characters

```
s=.[:(,.-&6)[:I.1([:*/p:)"1 i.,.6-~i.
```

Lost a character keeping both primes below the limit...and another 7 declaring a function.

Usage:

```
   s 100
11  5
13  7
17 11
19 13
23 17
29 23
37 31
43 37
47 41
53 47
59 53
67 61
73 67
79 73
89 83
```

**Edit**

Seems like a lot of the new answers are not creating functions, taking input or limiting both numbers in the pair to be below `n` - if I ignore those restrictions too I can get down to **28 characters**:

```
(,.6&+)I.*/"1[1 p:(i.,.6+i.)
```

Answer (score 6):

### *Mathematica*, 35

```
{#,#+6}&~Array~#~Cases~{__?PrimeQ}&
```

Answer (score 4):

#### GolfScript, 32 characters

```
~),2>{:P{(.P\%}do(!},:L{6+L?)},p
```

Since the output format was not specified, the code above will print the lower prime of each pair. Thus a number `x` is included if `x` and `x+6` are both prime and both are below `n`. Input is given as single number on STDIN.

```
> 150
[5 7 11 13 17 23 31 37 41 47 53 61 67 73 83 97 101 103 107 131]
```

Comment: I think you should print both primes. It's a part of the task.

Comment: @ugoren The task was changed after I submitted my version. I'll try and add that to my version soon.

Comment: Yes, your answer matches the original task.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>137 132 126 122</strike> 118

```python
f=lambda x:not[y for y in range(2,x)if x%y==0]
i=30
print [(x,y)for x in range(i)for y in range(i)if f(x)&f(y)&x-6==y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcuxCoNADADQ3a/IUrmAglhwKORLxOHEpg3YnBw3JF9/4lRwf@/w8k061sq0x9@6RbCXpjI7cMrgIAo56ucdxs5QGOzhRMPSCD2H5siiBeZgnePF7c8Fb1@uzcGw5eDYWj8R@VLrCQ)

Using list comprehensions, as well as the fact that `[] = False`

`f(x)` actually returns all the factors of `x`, and you can then work out prime-ness from that.

Comment: You can turn `f(x)` into `f=lambda x:not[y for y in range(2,x)if x%y==0]` to save a few characters. You can also reduce the `if`s at the end of your list comprehension with `f(x)&f(y)&(x-6==y)`.

Comment: @beary605 I don't really know a lot about lamdas (well, I know nothing), so I'll look in to that, but yes, anda not ifs.

Comment: A lambda is an anonymous function which returns a value. `a=lambda x,y,z:(value here)` is the same as `def a(x,y,z):return (value here)`.

Comment: Awesome, I seem to get the hang. Updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Python (<s>93 90 99</s> 95)

Yay for quick and dirty `isprime` functions!

```
a=lambda x:all(x%i for i in range(2,x));b=2
while b<input():
 b+=1
 if a(b)&a(b+6):print b,b+6
```

Comment: `1` instead of `True` will save you 3 characters...

Comment: Why do I keep missing that? Fixed.

Comment: You don't get a limit parameter. Also, `[]` in `all()` isn't needed (at least in Python 2.7).

Comment: Wow, really? Cool! I will implement the parameter.

Comment: I don't know why you subtract 1 from x, but you can remove that for 2 characters. Then you can replace the while loop with a for loops from 2 to input()+1 for another 2 characters.

Answer (score 3):

## [K3 / Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), 45

```
{a@&6=(-).'a:,/a,\:/:a:&{(x>1)&&/x!'2_!x}'!x}
```

.

```
{a@&6=(-).'a:,/a,\:/:a:&{(x>1)&&/x!'2_!x}'!x}100
(11 5
 13 7
 17 11
 19 13
 23 17
 29 23
 37 31
 43 37
 47 41
 53 47
 59 53
 67 61
 73 67
 79 73
 89 83)
```

And the same solution in the current incarnation of K which is identical to the K3 solution except for the fact that it does not have an inbuilt mod operator, which adds about 14 chars for 59

```
{a@&6=(-).'a:,/a,\:/:a:&{(x>1)&&/{x-y*x div y}[x;2_!x]}'!x}
```

Answer (score 3):

### C, <strike>102</strike> <strike>99</strike> 95 chars

Returning an array in C is something you try to avoid. So the function `s` gets the limit `n` and a pointer to an array of integers, and fills it with the data. Each pair of sexy primes is placed in two positions in the array. So `o[0]=5`, `o[1]=11`, `o[2]=7`, `o[3]=13`. The function assumes the array is large enough.

```
x=7,l;
p(){
    return++l>=x/2||x*(x-6)%l&&p();
}
s(int n,int*o){
    for(;l=++x<=n;)p()?*o++=x-6,*o++=x:0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### x86-Assembly (78 Bytes)

This example uses Intel syntax. Besides, here the `fastcall` or `register` calling convention is used (the latter from 32-bit Delphi), so the parameter is in `ecx`. I also introduce a second parameter that points to a free space for the result and is saved in `edx`. A function for allocating memory space would be specific to the operating system and a transfer via the stack would be problematic, so I chose this option.

```
listSexy:
   mov   ebp, esp      ; 89E5    Save initial esp
   mov   edi, edx      ; 89D7    Save second parameter in edx
   
   ; Part One: Save all prime numbers from 3 to the limit on the stack
   ; (This takes 32 Bytes)
   xor   eax, eax      ; 31C0    set eax = 1 (shorter than mov eax, 1)
   inc   eax           ; 40
checkComplete:
   add   eax, 2        ; 83C002  Go to next possible number (first is 3)
   cmp   eax, ecx      ; 39C8    Has the limit, i.e. the parameter, been skipped?
   jae   partTwo       ; 7316
   mov   ebx, esp      ; 89E3    Check it against all previous prime numbers
checkNext:             ;         which are stored between ebp and esp
   cdq                 ; 99      Clear edx for the later division
   push  eax           ; 50      Put the number on the stack
   cmp   ebx, ebp      ; 39E5    Has the check already completed?
   je    partTwo       ; 74F1    The comfirmed prime number remains on stack
   mov   esi, [ebx]    ; 8B33    Load a previous prime
   div   esi           ; F7F6
   pop   eax           ; 58
   test  edx, edx      ; 85D2    Is esi a divider?
   je    checkComplete ; 74E8
   add   ebx, 4        ; 83C304  Let ebx point to the next possible divisor
   jmp   checkNext     ; EBEC
   
   ; Part Zwo: Check all prime numbers if they are sexy primes
   ; (This takes 39 Bytes)
partTwo:
   mov   ebx, ebp      ; 89E5    Start with the first prime number, i.e. 3
NextPrime:
   sub   ebx, 4        ; 83EB04  Let ebx point to the next prime number
   cmp   ebx, esp      ; 39E3    Has the last number been reached? It cant be sexy,
                       ;         since it has no successors here
   jmp   Finished      ; 761E
   mov   edx, ebx      ; 89DA    Check all successors up to a distance of 6
   mov   eax, [ebx]    ; 8B03    eax is the prime number whose successors are checked
   add   eax, 6        ; 83C006
GoFurther:
   sub   edx, 4        ; 83EA04
   cmp   eax, [edx]    ; 8B02
   jb    NextPrime     ; 72EB    If the successor is too large, x can no longer be sexy
   ja    GoFurther     ; 77F7    If the successor is too small, take the next one
   mov   eax, [ebx]    ; 8B03    Load eax again (shorter than sub eax, 6)
   mov   ecx, [edx]    ; 8B0A    Load the successor which makes eax a sexy prime
   mov   [edi], eax    ; 8907    Store both in their intended place
   mov   [edi+4], ecx  ; 894F04
   add   edi, 8        ; 83C708
   jmp   NextPrime     ; EBDB

Finished:
   mov   esp, ebp      ; 89EC    Restore stack
   ret                 ; C3
```

The opcodes (and thus the size of the instruction) are given in the comment. The function can be called from C with, for example

```c
int n = 100;
int resultList[50] = { };
listSexy(n, resultList);
```

The result list should be initialized with zero, since no final null byte sequence or similar is written into.

Online working example: http://tpcg.io/mEPb1Wy9

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm not too familiar with Assembly, but I just wanted to make sure that your program follows the standard allowed [input/output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) methods? It seems as though it does, but the snippet of C code is making me unsure. Furthermore, make sure to take a look at [TryItOnline](https://tio.run/#) to see if any of the languages included can run your program, so that others can verify and help improve your answer

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks for your comment, I added a corresponding link and was able to fix a few typing errors too. From your link of the allowed input/output methods, however, I do not quite understand. My example provides a function, memory space for the return value is passed as a parameter at function call.

Comment: As I said, I‘m not very familiar with Assembly, so I can’t pass judgement on it’s validity. You can ask in our Chatroom, [TNB](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), and I‘m sure someone more knowledgeable could answer

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅPãʒÆ7+
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGvA4cWnJh1uM9f@/9/EHAA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w60BhxefmnS4zVz7f63O/2hDAx1jAx0Tcx1z01gA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ÅP       # Push a list of primes smaller than or equal to the (implicit) input-integer
  ã      # Create all possible pairs by taking the cartesian product with itself
         # (which will include inverted duplicates - i.e. both [5,11] and [11,5])
   ʒ     # Filter this list of pairs [a,b] by:
    Æ    #  Reduce it by subtracting: a-b
     7+  #  Add 7
         #  (only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E, so this will keep pairs that satisfy a-b+7==1)
         # (after which the resulting list of pairs is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <sup>12</sup> 10 bytes

*-2 thanks to @Fatalize*

```
≥Iṗ-₆ṗ;I≜ᶠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HnUs@HO6frPmpqA1LWno865zzctuD/f2OD/1EA)

#### How it works

```
≥Iṗ-₆ṗ;I≜ᶠ
         ᶠ find all …
        ≜   force number-finding of constraints that fulfill …
             (strictly not necessary, but otherwise constraints will be returned)
≥             any number less than the input
 I            assign it to I
  ṗ           must be prime
   -₆ṗ        minus 6 must also be prime
      ;I      append I again (so we have [I-6,I])
```

Comment: You can use findall directly on the labelling predicate, to save 2 bytes: [`≥Iṗ-₆ṗ;I≜ᶠ`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HnUs@HO6frPmpqA1LWno865zzctuD/f2OD/1EA)

Answer (score 2):

**Perl: 73 char**

```
sub p{(1x$_[0])!~/^(11+?)\1+$/}map{$x=$_+6;p($_)&&p($x)&&say"$_,$x"}2..<>
```

**usage:**

```
echo 30 | perl -E 'sub p{(1x$_[0])!~/^(11+?)\1+$/}map{$x=$_+6;p($_)&&p($x)&&say"$_,$x"}2..<>'
```

**output:**

```
5,11
7,13
11,17
13,19
17,23
23,29
```

Comment: Nice sulution with the regex. You can even shorten by 3 bytes: ```sub p{(1x$_[0])!~/^(11+?)\1+$/}map{p($_)&&p($_+6)&&say"$_,",$_+6}2..<>```

Answer (score 2):

## Octave 39

Modified my MATLAB answer to comply with the new (annoying) rules. `n` is your value.

```
p=@isprime;i=1:n;[j=i(p(i)&p(i+6));j+6]
```

Can be tested [here](http://www.online-utility.org/math/math_calculator.jsp)

Answer (score 2):

### R, 83 characters

```
f=function(n){library(gmp);p=isprime;for(i in 1:n)if(p(i)&p(i+6)){print(c(i,i+6))}}
```

Usage:

```
f(150)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <strike>99 88 86 84 82</strike> 78

```
f=->x{(9..x).map{|n|[n-6,n]if[n,n-6].all?{|t|(2...t).all?{|m|t%m>0}}}.compact}
```

Sample output:

`[[5, 11], [7, 13], [11, 17], [13, 19], [17, 23], [23, 29], [31, 37], [37, 43], [41, 47], [47, 53], [53, 59], [61, 67], [67, 73], [73, 79], [83, 89]]`

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby <s>75</s> 74

The new version uses [Artem Ice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4878/artem-ice)'s prime test method:

```ruby
z=->x{(9..x).map{|i|[i-6,i]}.select{|a|a.all?{|r|(2...r).all?{|m|r%m>0}}}}
```

Online test: http://ideone.com/yaOdn

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (<s>140</s> 113 Characters)

`t=(i,n)=>{for(n=i;n%--i;);return 1==i};s=(n,p)=>{for(p=[],i=2;i<n-6;i++)if(t(i)&&t(i+6))p.push([i,i+6]);return p}`

Try `s(30)`.

Updated to use the shorter primality test from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91309/5000), and to use the new arrow notation.

*Old version (140 characters):*

`function t(n,i){for(i=2;i<n;i++)if(!(n%i))return!1;return!0}function s(n,p){for(p=[],i=2;i<n-6;i++)if(t(i)&&t(i+6))p.push([i,i+6]);return p}`

Answer (score 2):

## J, 25 chars

```
(#~*/"1@p:~&1)(,+&6)"0 i.
```

`i.n` creates a range of [0,n)

`(,+&6)"0` takes each integer `n` in the list and makes a pair `n, n+6`

`(#~ condition)` is basically a `filter`, and the condition in this case, `*/"1@p:~&1`, just checks if a pair is composed solely of primes.

Answer (score 2):

## C# (279 characters)

Basically, it's Saumil's solution with a couple of tweaks. I don't have <s>enough</s> any reputation for commenting though, so...

```
using System;namespace X{public class P{static int l=100;static void Main(){F(0);}static bool I(int n){bool b=1>0;if(n==1){b=1<0;}for(int i=2;i<n;++i){if(n%i==0){b=1<0;break;}}return b;}static void F(int p){if((p+6)<=l){if(I(p+6)&&I(p)){Console.WriteLine(p+6+","+p);}F(p+1);}}}}
```

**Output:**

```
11,5
13,7
17,11
19,13
23,17
29,23
37,31
43,37
47,41
53,47
59,53
67,61
73,67
79,73
89,83
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

Outputs in reversed order, because the K3 answer also seems to do that.

```
LεD6-‚}ʒpP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f59xWFzPdRw2zak9NKgj4/9/QwAAA)

## Explanation

```
L           Length range
 ε          Map:
  D             Duplicate
   6-           Minus 6
     ‚          Pair
      }         Reverse the pair
       ʒ    Filter:
        p       Is_prime
         P      in both items
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>104</s> 75 bytes

*-29 bytes thanks to @emanresuA*

```javascript
g=x=>--x>6&&g(x,(f=(n,t=2)=>t<n?n%t&&f(n,t+1):n>1)(x)*f(x-6)&&print(x-6,x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsIwEABf47KrSbEKRcTEuwc9@IJSTIiUTWmWsr4@trdhZr790pdhTpPY5VJrdOq8teo7gIhqMDhkI@5EzsuN77wTgLCpQ0tX9i2h0j6g2o4ApjmxbGyUqA6ZSx4/zZgjPt6vZ1Nk7TGFH0Y8H2ld/g)

Comment: [102](https://tio.run/##FYhPC4IwFMA/TfIezocWSEhTunaoQ0eRGNLmwubYluinX3r6/fmIWfjeaRuy@RwVjwuvWyK6OidWWLISO/oKC/BiGnkNkoNhgR83DxfTmENo5H7SAqu8MnWBoDFJJOi03GjJ/vwArWZbd8gsb7t9x34yfhrfNE4Kbs/HnXxw2igtV1BwyhEx/gE)

Comment: [98 with a for loop](https://tio.run/##FchBC4IwFADgv9Ilea@paIGEOr13qENH8SDi1gvZxjbFiH77quP3PYd1cKMl45P1HCQPG2/eQlsgnsWGd33FGNVbUlQIgoOKPT8ib3ytWrX3rfgPy7HMStXkCIQHAcQKjCKTmsU9oKP45x4rO/nFqp35hFErp@cpnbWEy/12TZ23pCSJF0g4ZYgYvg)

Comment: [81](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEEDR0xhmTFtahSKmiXsXuvAEpZgwUialGUpFPHu0y//4r37p0zDTJOVyysHm1bqPjzOQrY3W1K1laxC8BS7EHtA66fjCO1HKb6QbPLNrEAj3Hki3qNQ0EwtQsZX55iFyiuOzGmOA6@N@q5L8h0D@DQGONSLmHw) with a different output format

Comment: @emanresuA You might want to write a separate answer, since those are some major golfs.

Comment: Nah, you can have it. ([75](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsIwEABf47KrSbEKRcTEuwc9@IJSTIiUTWmWsr4@trdhZr790pdhTpPY5VJrdOq8teo7gIhqMDhkI@5EzsuN77wTgLCpQ0tX9i2h0j6g2o4ApjmxbGyUqA6ZSx4/zZgjPt6vZ1Nk7TGFH0Y8H2ld/g))

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Rż+¥6ẒẠ$Ƈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//UsW8K8KlNuG6kuG6oCTGh/8sw4fFkuG5mCRLKVn//zMwLCA0Nw)

### How it works

```
Rż+¥6ẒẠ$Ƈ - Main link. Takes N on the left
R         - Range; R = [1, 2, ..., N]
   ¥6     - Previous 2 links as a dyad f(R, 6):
  +       -   Add 6 to each element in R
 ż        -   Zip together
       $Ƈ - Keep those pairs for which the following is true:
      Ạ   -   Are all elements...
     Ẓ    -   ...prime?
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 131 bytes

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(A1),y,TRANSPOSE(x),z,x*(MMULT((MOD(x,y)=0)*1,x^0)=2),a,IFERROR(INDEX(z,x+{0,6}),),FILTER(a,MMULT(SIGN(a),{1;1})=2))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnC1DBGDIMcR3NdvZ?e=mhqbY1)

### Explanation

- `=LET(` allows defined names within formulas.
- `x,SEQUENCE(A1),` x = `1..A1` listed vertically.
- `y,TRANSPOSE(x),` y = `1..A1` listed horizontally.
- `(MOD(x,y)=0)*1` creates a matrix this is 1 if x mod y = 0 and 0 otherwise.
- `MMULT(~,x^0)` sums the elements of each row with matrix multiplication. `x^0` is a vertical matrix of 1s.
- `z,x*(~=2),` if the sum = 2 then `x` is prime and `z=x` else `z=0`.
- `,a,IFERROR(INDEX(z,x+{0,6}),),` creates an array `a` where the first column is `z` and the second is `z` offset by 6 rows.
- `FILTER(a,MMULT(SIGN(a),{1;1})=2)` returns the rows of `a` that have no zeros.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica - <strike>69</strike> 48 chars

Assuming m has been assigned a value

```
p=PrimeQ;Cases[Range@m,n_/;p@n&&p[n+6]:>{n,n+6}]
```

Answer (score 1):

### C# 295

```cs
using System;using System.Linq;namespace K{class C{public static void Main(string[]a){Func<int,bool>p=i=>Enumerable.Range(2,i-3).All(x=>i%x>0);Console.WriteLine("["+String.Join(",",Enumerable.Range(0,int.Parse(a[0])).Where(i=>i>9&&p(i)&&p(i-6)).Select(i=>"["+(i-6)+","+i+"]").ToArray())+"]");}}}
```

Online test: http://ideone.com/4PwTW *(in this test I've replaced `int.Parse(a[0])` with the actual int value, as I cannot supply command line arguments to programs running on ideone.com)*

Answer (score 1):

## Scala (82)

```
def p(n:Int)=9 to n map(x=>List(x-6,x))filter(_.forall(l=>2 to l-1 forall(l%_>0)))
```

Sample output:
`Vector(List(5, 11), List(7, 13), List(11, 17), List(13, 19), List(17, 23), List(23, 29), List(31, 37), List(37, 43), List(41, 47), List(47, 53), List(53, 59), List(61, 67), List(67, 73), List(73, 79), List(83, 89))`

Answer (score 1):

## Factor 140

This language is fun and interesting. My first script.

```
:: i ( n -- ? )
n 1 - 2 [a,b] [ n swap mod 0 > ] all? ;
:: s ( n -- r r )
11 n [a,b] [ i ] filter [ 6 - ] map [ i ] filter dup [ 6 + ] map ;
```

Usage:

```
( scratchpad ) 100 f

--- Data stack:
V{ 5 7 11 13 17 23 31 37 41 47 53 61 67 73 83 }
V{ 11 13 17 19 23 29 37 43 47 53 59 67 73 79 89 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**PARI/GP  (62 characters)**

```
f(a)=w=[];forprime(x=0,a,isprime(x+6)&w=concat(w,[[x,x+6]]));w
```

Example:

```
 (00:01) gp > f(a)=w=[];forprime(x=0,a,isprime(x+6)&w=concat(w,[[x,x+6]]));w
 (00:01) gp > f(30)
 %1 = [[5, 11], [7, 13], [11, 17], [13, 19], [17, 23], [23, 29]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (65 chars)

```
p n=[(x,x+6)|x<-[3..n-6],all(\k->all((>0).mod k)[2..k-1])[x,x+6]]
```

The output:

```
Prelude> p 100
[(5,11),(7,13),(11,17),(13,19),(17,23),(23,29),(31,37),(37,43),(41,47),(47,53),(
53,59),(61,67),(67,73),(73,79),(83,89)]
```

---

**About the [MATLAB answer here:](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6468/5021)**

*(I spent all my rep on a bounty so can't comment just yet)*. Google says: " the Matlab's isprime function ... is based on the probabilistic Miller-Rabin". So it seems that the MATLAB entry should be disqualified.

Answer (score 1):

### R <s>85</s> 81 characters

```
f=function(n){m=2:n;a=m[rowSums(!outer(m,m,`%%`))<2];cbind(b<-a[(a+6)%in%a],b+6)}
```

Example run:

```
f(50)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    5   11
 [2,]    7   13
 [3,]   11   17
 [4,]   13   19
 [5,]   17   23
 [6,]   23   29
 [7,]   31   37
 [8,]   37   43
 [9,]   41   47
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 106 bytes

```php
function p($n){for($i=$n;--$i&&$n%$i;);return$i-1;}for(;++$i<$argv[1]-5;)p($i)|p($k=$i+6)?:print"$i,$k\n";
```

program prints pairs as `n,n+6` delimited by linebreaks. Run with `-r`.

I modified my [is_prime function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39743570#39743570) (& saved a byte) so that it returns `0` for primes to golf on the Elvis.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CJam), 27 bytes

```
ri),{__6+_mp@mp&{pp}{;;}?}%
```

It prints pairs as two lines with one number each on then, largest to smallest. See the TIO for the example from the question.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vyhTU6c6Pt5MOz63wCG3QK26oKC22tq61r5W9f9/YwMA)

Explanation:

```
ri                              input an integer
  )                             increment
   ,{                    }%     iterate "m" from 0 to n-1
     __                         create two copies
       6+                       add 6
         _                      copy
          mp                    check if m+6 is prime
            @                   rotate so m is on top
             mp                 check if m is prime
               &                bitwise AND on two prime checks
                        ?       ternary if-else
                {pp}            if primes, print top two numbers
                    {;;}        otherwise, discard them
```

Answer (score 0):

**C# ( <strike>321</strike> <strike>303</strike> 290 characters )**

`using System;namespace X{public class P{ static int l=100;static void Main(){F(0);}static bool I(int n){bool b=true;if(n==1){b=false;}for(int i=2;i<n;++i){if(n%i==0){b=false;break;}}return b;}static void F(int p){if((p+6)<=l){int m=p+6;if(I(m)&&I(p)){Console.WriteLine(m+","+p);}F(p+1);}}}}`

**Output:**
11,5
13,7
17,11
19,13
23,17
29,23
37,31
43,37
47,41
53,47
59,53
67,61
73,67
79,73
89,83

Comment: Welcome to CodeGolf! You can save some chars if you give the class and methods one-letter names (ex: `class P` instead of `class Program`).

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 61 bytes

```ruby
->n{Prime.take_while{_1<=n}.map{[_1,_1+6]}.select{_2.prime?}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnW0km5RQVFmbqpS7CI326WlJWm6Fjdtde3yqgNAonolidmp8eUZmTmp1fGGNrZ5tXq5iQXV0fGGOvGG2maxtXrFqTmpySXV8UZ6YGPsa2shhiwvUHCLNjaIhfAWLIDQAA)

Answer (score 0):

## POSIX Shell Command Language + Utilities + seq + 4.1BSD factor, 101 bytes

```sh
seq 2 $1|factor|sed '/: .* /d;s/:.*//'>q
while read a;do grep -x $((a+6)) q&&echo $a;done<q|paste - -
```

seq generates integers in [2, specified], factor turns them into this format we all know and love:

```sh
2: 2
3: 3
4: 2 2
5: 5
6: 2 3
```

sed deletes lines with a space after the first colon-space (i.e. non-primes), then trims off everything after the colon.
For each prime a, we copy the prime equal to a+6 to the standard output stream, and if that succeeded, also write a, then we paste each pair of output lines together.

Any seq since its introduction in Version 8 AT&T UNIX works, and you can trivially replace it with a while at a cost of 42 bytes. Any factor since its introduction in Version 7 AT&T UNIX works (sans format quirks maybe, I'm not in the mood for reading PDP-11 assembly; if the format is space-less, then 4.1BSD probably has the right one).

Transcript of test cases:

```sh
$ cat d.sh; echo; wc -c d.sh
seq 2 $1|factor|sed '/: .* /d;s/:.*//'>q
while read a;do grep -x $((a+6)) q&&echo $a;done<q|paste - -
101 d.sh
$ ./d.sh 30
11      5
13      7
17      11
19      13
23      17
29      23
```

Herein an "array of arrays" is a set of lines containing tab-delimited fields.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õ í7ôU)fÈej
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9SDtN/RVKWbIZWo&input=MzAKLVE)