# Are they collinear?

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem, geometry

## Task

Write a program/function that when given three 2d points in [cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) as input outputs a truthy value if they are [collinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinearity) otherwise a falsey value

Three points are said to be collinear if there exists a straight line that passes through all the points

You may assume that the coordinates of the three points are integers and that the three points are distinct.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest bytes wins

## Sample Testcases

```
(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3) -> Truthy
(1, 1), (2, 2), (10, 10) -> Truthy
(10, 1), (10, 2), (10, 3) -> Truthy
(1, 10), (2, 10), (3, 10) -> Truthy
(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4) -> Falsey
(1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2) -> Falsey
(-5, 70), (2, 0), (-1, 30) -> Truthy
(460, 2363), (1127, 2392), (-1334, 2285) -> Truthy
(-789, -215), (-753, -110), (518, -780) -> Falsey
(227816082, 4430300), (121709952, 3976855), (127369710, 4001042) -> Truthy
(641027, 3459466), (475989, 3458761), (-675960, 3453838) -> Falsey
```

Comment: May we take the input points as complex numbers?

Comment: Are three points guaranteed to be distinct?

Comment: @fireflame241 yes complex numbers as input is acceptable

Comment: @Bubbler the three points are guaranteed to be different updated the question to reflect that

Answer (score 14):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 21 bytes

Takes a matrix `[x1, y1; x2, y2; x3, y3]` as input.

```matlab
@(a)~det([a,[1;1;1]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY87CsNADET7nGJLG2yjv7QsgdzDuDD5tGlCylzd0WLUjJ5GjPS@f/bv83iV67Isx23Yx9/j@RnWfVqxZW3beLyGVQymQmzcCiJ515VamZFZsqHQbbykb/aoU5kJNYeunBoRWlGMlB5w2og80CBoKiIMDGlBQodaNRlXt1DtzNmqY4YLAILQuW@C0K9g0SpmrYhr7ckJwg0z3JL0o5NwcOQbfw)

Comment: You can shorten to `@(a)~det([a,e(3,1)])` (the output is suject to floating-point errors even with your current approach)

Answer (score 12):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 39 bytes

```javascript
(a,b,c,d,e,f)=>a*d+c*f+e*b==b*c+d*e+f*a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHdatwwEIXv/RRDrmR7tNG/ZIKTi8I@Qe66hdXacrtliYPthITSZ99KWmjXpJQajDWHb@Yca777Vz930/F5oU9jH87b9kw8HrDDHgMOZXvvq77uqqEO1aFtD1VX91Woh8qfX/0ES5iXT34OM7SwJxyBlwhEIIj0lQiyBHoPj9PL8u29@ABwFgX2TyTOUBnY@tMc1gD7DV4DVCNYdo3Q2CPXNspEayGNzDG4sKlqxIWWUsVSOL1qodY1CFRwnSmrYzTKeXbQ3MXCOrZKIoR13DAXcyglmWSZ5YJb1jQ6qrKxxml9Ua00jU03ohjjTImVuVGcpZBS6UYZkzqU1U1KFCVnTb4TaqKW/ixq0kl3lWa/mZ9Px2Vf7O@KYhgnIGl/RxiHP0ss4UcB8fmM4BEOCB1CjxAQBoTpS9zx7Y4Q@rDr6@yWD7t4/H81BSKb8nYT3kJHjuVdNpzi6Pi2cPN4c1G68WkeT2FzGr@Sv2RB2H6Qyzjs5/kX)

Accepts input as `(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)`. Uses the shoelace formula to determine if the enclosed area is 0.

#### Explanation

The [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) states that, the area of a polygon can be calculated using the coordinates of its vertices. Specifically, assuming the vertices are \$P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_n\$ so that \$P_1P_2, P_2P_3, \cdots, P_{n-1}P_n, P_nP_1\$ are the edges of the polygon, then the area \$A\$ can be calculated with

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\left|(x_1y_2+x_2 y_3+\cdots+x_{n-1}y_n+x_ny_1)-(y_1x_2+y_2x_3 +\cdots+y_{n-1}x_n+y_nx_1)\right|$$

where \$(x_n,y_n)\$ are the coordinates of \$P_n\$.

Taking \$n=3\$, we have the formula for the area of a triangle with coordinates \$(x_1,y_1)\$, \$(x_2,y_2)\$ and \$(x_3,y_3)\$:

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\left|(x_1y_2+x_2y_3+x_3y_1)-(y_1x_2+y_2x_3+y_3x_1)\right|$$

Three points are collinear if and only if the triangle constructed by these points has a zero area (otherwise, one of the points lies away from the line segment between the other two points, giving a non-zero area to the triangle). Since we only need to check whether the area is 0, the 1/2 and the absolute can be ignored. This boils down to checking whether

$$(x_1y_2+x_2y_3+x_3y_1)-(y_1x_2+y_2x_3+y_3x_1)=0$$

or after rearranging terms

$$x_1y_2+x_2y_3+x_3y_1=y_1x_2+y_2x_3+y_3x_1$$

Comment: I love this.  It's exactly the same length as ```(c-a)*(f-b)==(d-b)*(e-a)``` (which seemed more intuitive to me), but now I've been introduced to the 'shoelace formula' that I'd never heard of before!

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
_ÆḊ¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@cNvDHV2H1vz//z/ayMjcwtDMwMJIR8HExNjA2MAg9n@0oZGhuYGlpSlQ0NjS3MzC1DRWRwEoam5sZmluaABUamBgaGBiFAsA)

Takes the differences `[(a-b), (a-c)]` via automatic vectorization of `a-[b-c]` then checks if the determinant (`ÆḊ`) is 0 (`¬`).

Answer (score 10):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>9</s></sup> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
0=11○÷.-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZG/ahtBEMb7e4otY7gLMzv7t0iahGC1sXEviGyzCDvISmFCqoDBCTJJEVwlYPwAKtPLb7Ivcv721ha6Jmn29vvmm5u5@00/zrsPl9P5@Umfb369nRzlqx/c0yvmfPv94e/Lrj@Gk1c3@dvXzVry1U/EDt6/wXm4PznoObE6VuXUSTdV4VacHSVJdmuUmEZVs1U0vGeztsnTk7FZcxJqjKOkxUkZx9rjHnWpiZikdbBo8iGmzVqzRQbKChQzKcshlSo1WvvAjoJOxggJlRms2VOMVieJ3gVr4Xhx0WNPQ8RkdOMME2aKsdE4hybjbcQ0GME7xjQHAxvCkCChaT7n1Z8veXWfr@9I5dVvNTk5O1/M1PJ0phazi2XzglvFe63aPnWr9J7qXqvDxafl6WUzLuAprZJ/Bphg0P/eYYbAu@n8YjYO0GiL50BnW@VpN9KhR8ZjAAd9oDOsgf9XVNQ1DUKQQDRq6UCrVR1oDSnQggKtogAMAsBGm2zh4RsqvWHaMz4sVflV9wkhspXhaHjliY4KtHRUooNVkA5LVaiDV6jubNM/Ag)

<sup>-1 byte thanks to @Jo King.</sup>

Takes one complex number (A) on the left, and two complex numbers (B and C) on the right. APL automatically maps scalars, so `A - B C` gives `(A-B)(A-C)`. Then divide between the two `÷.`, and check if the result's imaginary part `11○` is zero `0=`.

Uses `⎕DIV←1`, so if division by zero would occur (because `A=C`), `÷` returns 0 instead, which obviously has imaginary part of zero, giving truthy as a result.

Comment: Would cause a division by zero if `A=C`. Maybe check if the phases `12○` are equal or (A-B)*conjugate of (A-C) is real.

Comment: @fireflame241 Phase equal doesn't work because the two can be in opposite direction. Multiplying conjugate sounds good, and is also free from possible float inaccuracies (should work at the cost of 2 bytes).

Comment: "Uses `⎕DIV←1`" - this is necesssary and is code (not a flag making a different "language") so shouldn't it be part of the byte count?

Comment: @JonathanAllan It is a system setting, which can be set outside the interpreter [as an environment variable](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#UNIX_IUG/Environment%20Variables.htm). Not counting system setting in code length is also mentioned [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14232/78410).

Comment: @JoKing Of course it does.

Comment: (For the lazy: "[not including system settings in the byte count] is justified by the existence of systems where the needed setting is default.")

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:(a-b)*(a-c-(a-c)%1*2)%1==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDdioMwEIXvfYqhsKAlKflPLNjLfYK9290Lay0VohVNl/r03YmFtrKwN9E5882ck/RTOJ07cTsWXzdftvtDCSXZk2qblnSfrfGsaDyyN74WeBQFuzVtfx4CjNOYHM8D@KaroelivRnDoem2CXgC9bWvq1AfoIC27NMxDNgdmp7MA5ux901IV3S3yrIEPWFPoEL2szq3va@v6ZXAlEE0uJIp7q9/Sp/67Dt5Xf38LWD1MVzCaVolMNTjxQdsH9P5NujQD00XHo3n4C3lBHhGIBUERPxKAjIDuoP7uuQPwBkK7F8Ed6gZeC/9WC8B9gBfAaoJWPaKUJyRSxtl0FpII@cYXNhY5eJOS6mwFE4vRqh1OQEquJ4pqzEa5Xx20NxhYR1bJBHCOm6YwxxKSSbZzHLBLctzjarMrXFa31UrTW7jiyjGOFNiYW4UZzGkVDpXxsQJZXUeE6HkrJnfhBrU4s1Qk066lzS/)

**Input**: the 3 points as 3 complex numbers
**Output**: True or False.

**How**

Let the 3 points be \$(a,A), (b,B), (c,C)\$

The 3 points are colinear iff \$(a-b)*(A-C)=(A-B)*(a-c)\$. Note that this formula doesn't have division, and thus won't have floating point issue.
Consider the following complex multiplication:
$$ \big((a-b)+(A-B)i\big) * \big((a-c)-(A-C)i\big)$$
The imaginary part of the result is:
$$(a-c)(A-B)-(a-b)(A-C)$$
which must be \$0\$ for the 3 points to be colinear.

Let `a`, `b`, `c` be the complex representation of the 3 points, then the condition above is equivalent to:

```python
t = (a-b) * (a-c).conjugate()
t.imag == 0
```

Instead of using `imag` and `conjugate`, we can take advantage of the fact that all points are integers. For a complex number `t` where both the real and imaginary parts are integers, `t%1` gives the imaginary part of `t`. Thus:

```python
t % 1 == t.imag * 1j
t - t % 1 * 2 == t.conjugate()
```

---

Old solution that doesn't use complex number

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda a,A,b,B,c,C:(a-b)*(A-C)==(A-B)*(a-c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDNTuswEIX3eYpRVzaykf/tIAUJkO4TsAMWaZuKSG5qJQa1T987TgU0QmLlnONvzpw4nfL7YdDnXfN6ju1@vW2hZQ9szR7Zhj3dkZav6Q154E@0afB4RNHyDT33@3QYM0ynqdodRoj90EE/FH075W0/3FUQGXTH1G1yt4UG9m0iUx7xduwTmwdupxT7TFb8fkUp8ki9HKHEpZLVfbaRRDobx2Kkt@o68eezgdXz@JHfT6sKxm76iBmvd@QmYmoa@yGTL/dnip6JZCApA6IYqHJqBpoCv4dLWPULkAIN8SeCGWYG/rVx6paA@AavAW4ZeHGNcJzRyzXG4WqlnZ5rSOWLqtWF1tqgVMEuRrgPNQOupJ0pb7Eal3LeYGVA4YNYNFHKB@lEwB7GaKHFzEolvahri66uvQvWXlyvXe3LixghpDBqsdwZKUpJbWxtnCsTxtu6NEIreDe/CXfolT9DTwcdrtr8Bw)

**Input**: the 2 coordinates of the first point, then the 2nd point, then the 3rd point.
**Output**: True or False.

---

This should work theoretically, but doesn't because of floating point imprecision:

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:((a-b)/(a-c)).imag==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDNbqswEIX3PMUoK1uyU//bVKLLPkF3t10QQlokQxC4VXj63DFR26Ar3Q1mznwz59jjkj7Og76eqtdrrPvDsYaaHVjzSEjND/QBvw2l@66v36tKXLt@PE8J5mUuTucJYje00A253s/p2A2PBUQG7WVsm9QeoYK@HsmcJuxO3cjWgf08xi6RHX/aUVqgHRwYNMj@ac79GNsLuTBYKGSDC1vy/varjiTSt@J@9e9vBbuX6TN9LLsCpnb@jAnbJ7JeBB3GqRsS@W78DtIrkQwkZUAUA5VPzUBT4E9w21f8A0iBgvgvgjvMCjzXcW63gPgB7wFuGXhxj3Cc0Vsb49BaaafXGFL5XJXqRmttsFTBbka4DyUDrqRdKW8xGpdydbAyYOGD2CRRygfpRMAcxmihxcpKJb0oS4uqLr0L1t5Ur13p84sYIaQwamPujBQ5pDa2NM7lCeNtmROhFLxb34Q71PLNUNNBh7s0fwE)

**Input**: 3 points, each represented by a complex number
**Output**: True or False.

Answer (score 8):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>13</sup> 7 bytes

```
0=-/ .*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVBNSwQxDL37K4II60p3TJO0aVf2orAn8SB7Hzy4iHjy4@CvH5OZURTpQArJ63uvL30eTrvVEXZbWEEAhK2dTQc397f7AXebS@guhvVwfnVcAwPBGcTgBUDBC4CDXQDcXXdweP14f/o8WSBHNADbdJz53vwIlu1x9p8aXvb/n11m8v7h5e2xRf5@g5rkPgVQ/E3vTcztKJJ9Rc48bhlJfao0KZnFRiqpKe@11AA9xTQqNJlPH6c/SLEEJ2AzLZGWmLHYcyKMjKMuUlSsNRnKVXNJaUKVc1W3FsSIQs1QWSL6IiypSs6uFk3VkxpUNI//2WfDfHvDuHD5k/IL)

Uses [the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinearity#Collinearity_of_points_whose_coordinates_are_given). J's generalized determinant `u .v` is defined for non-square matrices, still multiplying (`*`) each x value with the difference of the other two y values (`-/`), finally reducing that result (`-/`). `-/ .*` calculates the determinant, check if it is `0=`.

Comment: Change `,.` to `,` by taking the input transposed.

Comment: @Bubbler it's even simpler. :-)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 22 bytes

```r
function(x)lm(1:3~x)$d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNasMwEIX3PYUWXcggw/xIM1Iht@gF2hRDoHHAJNTd9OruTKBdBWQkxOjpm6cnLdt02KbbfLyeLnNch89zxBf@WYfnj22K57frclrjMWLCRDY48ZDCvFy@DpzC@7cXr8Pw9ABFsNmFDXLyju@x/kP3eP9nzvtQ96YeOpakcIdHTNwNkQVSIBY7RyT1ulEKIzJn21At3Qu1NmsgLLZqYW@2HwgFqwu1G4FIKwpUuzZnBgZrRkKF1opp3FRqKa4pS1P3zgAImULPWjKCP4pzaVnEGrU0j2tCVUELKKb4H5jClesjx@0X)

Finally a challenge which calls for `lm`!

The function `lm` performs linear regression. Here, we are using the input `x` as covariates, and `1 2 3` as observations (any vector of length 3 would do).

The output is an object with many components; of interest here is `df.residual` (which can be accessed with the unambiguous abbreviation `$d`), the residual degrees of freedom. This number corresponds to the number of observations minus the number of parameters being estimated. Now:

- if the points are not collinear, the regression proceeds normally, estimating 3 parameters, so `df.residual == 0`.
- if the points are collinear, there is an identifiability issue and only 2 parameters can be estimated (the last will be given as `NA`), so `df.residual == 1`.

Note that the final test case fails due to numerical precision issues.

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
Det@{#2-#,#3-#}==0&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY@xbsMwDER3f4UAAZkogBQlURpceOgHtOhYdDCCBM2QDIU7Gcqvu5Tipe0i4d4Rx@N1Xj5P13m5HOftPG7Pp2VarXcWLDtbxxEP2@v3RenL1@W2vFv3dJ4m@3G4vx3n230d1pWAKqwevL4MXCv8gYRA@B8zhN8Qd6tDF8GIEqPI9N8RGN5zQkIwnhM3g8hLU8U/xpiDSp/jniS5gHGeYrclsiqinhkpq5C8x3ovmRJmXRkCI2MfIk@CpUSlXCTlGB9UOBXR40xAJAx78RQIWx8OsYSU2miQWFoHRVkS9RpJWTtCGWfOtQ512H4A)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 27 bytes

```r
function(m)!det(cbind(1,m))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBNasQwDIX3PUW6s2EMsiVLMvQYvUCbmUAWycCQQm@fSmkL04WnoGD75dPTz22fhpe0Tx/ruM3XNSzx@XzZwvg@r@eQT0uM@xSWt@02f4bRhMGiHIEW8Tjs8RrjU4fL4F@XhAP144d9aHqHPXT92yf9y337lh6X6mkQ@CWT5WC3NrGDyN5gLuL3VjwJkexRtHariDYDS7ZqSSp6ko9as7qg3ZKliGYGtT9ECAi@1JIFWqu@gSastbomyE3ckwAyUHdgpgzeO1JtxGy81ObdmaDCtoDEpviopqCi3jvtXw)

Port of alephalpha's [Octave answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206843/78274).

Comment: Bah!  You beat me by 22 bytes within 11 seconds!

Comment: Well, it's just a different approach that, btw, I have learned just now :D

Comment: 22 bytes using lm: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206894/86301 :-)

Comment: `det(diff(m))` would work, I think

Comment: @Giuseppe, not really, the penultimate test case already gives a quite noticeable deviation from zero: [TIO](https://tio.run/##hZBLagMxDIb3PcUsxxCDZMmSDDlGLlCSDMwiKYQp9PYTaZJCunAK8uv3p@dtnYZ9Xqfv63GZv67jJZ3Oy3iap8mvafX9c7nNP@NxxN3gVjYjt7Qd/jik9NHhEGJ1SdjQOJ7s26Av2Nuof@vkf7lH3NLjct0NCr9kdh/q5mYJkCQKxKJxbyWciNgfxWo3i1pzsKBny1opnKLVihaCdVOWooYC5j/MBAQx1IIKrdWYQFOxWkNTkqYRkwEQuNuwMELUTlwbizivtUV1LpiKDyCLK9GqK2Rkr5HWOw)

Comment: I think that's still just a numerical precision issue since R "upgrades" `integer` to `double` once it gets past 32 bits. Assuming an arbitrary precision integer type, it should work, although I haven't been able to test that fully, since `diff` doesn't play nicely with `gmp::as.bigz`

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```perl6
{!im [/] $^a X-@_:}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDNagJBEITvPkUHQtB1Brun51fIzylPkENATViIJgu7iWhyEPXZNz0rBBchcxm6@GqqptfLTe3bZgc3K7iFdn9VNTCbLOD6pYRn/fA6Pbarrw0M6@pzuR3BfgBytuUOVnCYHZpyDcW4gKJSzfR9Mtf387fxZDE4tkNSQCMFQ6PA5JsV8Aj0HTxtfr4/doMLgFAE/BeRN2wHPJb1dtkH8A88B7RTEPAc0eLhfoz1Em3Yc1eDTMhTMiea2cpooutZdIhJgTbkOio4qaaJugRHUYYQsdfEmBDJY5Qe1jIydiwZCpiSE5VT8NG5kxrYp5A3YhEJremFe0uYS7J1yXqfHTa4lBuJFIPvdqK9aPlnonHkeNbmFw)

Takes input as three complex numbers and returns a boolean. Note that if the last and first points are identical (which is disallowed in the challenge spec), then the division operation would return NaN for dividing by zero, which boolifies to True for some reason, so this would fail.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 49 bytes

```r
function(p,q=p-p[,1])q[1,3]*q[2,2]==q[2,3]*q[1,2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZGxboQwDIb3PkWkLlAlkh0ncTLQsU/QDd1wpVcVCXHA3Q19epoAV9SqEkyxf@n77d8ZxurcNHV7Og7F@HFrq2t9brNO9kWnulLiIe9LlHR46kst9aEo0ju1GNsVzqq3un3PqgylwFyKKtNS6KkgKSjPc/Eo1LN4HW7Xz6@HPRxClGAHCXc0VSu7cyjcpy4V7Zz6X07zw70cm8tpi4PVYJNTVgqG36SKZrRjV@PSYcjRfBvUnNqgFxMiE3vt7baTYh@kUBrtzLKNqRUup7PoY8cetuNozR4d@JjFGAKC2QE1MoRgo0yBnbd2kZlc4PSrBgDB6O1VnUFIQcnYYJybfAzbkAJEzbOb/0G5KKYDRZE8@b@7j98)

How?

- Subtract first point from the other two:
- if points are on a line, the line must now pass through (x=0,y=0)
- so we check that the gradient=y/x is identical for both other points: y2/x2==y3/x3
- but to avoid dividing by zero, we rearrange: y2*x3==y3*x2

Edit:

- which, thanks to [Kirill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206838/are-they-collinear/206850#206850), [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206843/78274) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant), I've now discovered is simply the *determinant* of the matrix (x2,y2,x3,y3)
- so, for only [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##jZHBTsMwDIbvPEUQl0RKJDtO4uTAjjwBN7TD6IqoVHVT6Q48fZesHRUIqT3V/tXvt3@nH6tT2zZdfeifx49LVw3NqZNn9XisB3l@0wb3Jn9wr5YfZfXedEdZSdQClRaVtFrYW0FakFJKPAmzE6/9Zfj8ftjCIWQJNpBwR0u1sBuHwn3qXNHGqf/ldD/cy6H9qtc4WAxWOeO1YPhNmmxGG3Z1oRyGAk23QculTXY2IXK5t9GvOxmOSQtj0U8s@5za4Hw6jzF3HGE9jrUcMUDMWZwjIJgc0CJDSj7LlDhE72eZKSQur@oAEJxdXzU4hBKUnE8uhJuPY59KgKxFDtM7mJDFcqAsUqT4d/fxCg): `function(p)!det(p[,-1]-p[,1])`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> <s>17</s> <s>27</s> 21 bytes

```
-Dн_iIн¹нQë`s/Uн¹н-X*¹θ+IθQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fN@zQTt0LeyMv7I3PjD@8OjKhWF/r0M5zO7QDz@34/z/aUEfBMJYLRBlBKONYAA)

[Verify All Test Cases!](https://tio.run/##XY@9SkNBEIVf5ZJOncX5278qz2AjhOuSKFikEgwIKWytxbcQIXWaNDd9yDP4Ite5e6MQm53lmzOHc55W9w/Lx/5lPZ00328fzWS6Xuzfn7vP3t12G3fczY67@XK@/5otVteX3eawvbo5bPtXuLjr27YloAItA9srIMXGGSMEwpFixTZO/E@MVV2H/Kqdhzjy4XUEMnINdi9BBgviaP/MVSCiwJx8VTHHRAETg6qg4OBBTBFz9gySY0jeVxYl5GhhFJFQ2a6b/6X0rBSeNjVkTBkc02DlohdwVFt4SmC7MXFQQgsq6rOGYESjz3ZnIMUwmLpgxHoZkSSplPID)

*-1 byte due to remembering implicit input exists and that variable assignment pops values*

*+10 due to bug fix regarding vertical lines :-(*

*-6 thanks to the wonderful @Kevin, who always manages to golf my 05AB1E answers! :D. Go and upvote his posts!*

### Explained

Before we even begin to look at the program, let's take a look at the maths needed to see if three points are collinear. Let our first point have co-ordinates \$(x_1, y_1)\$, our second point have co-ordinates \$(x_2, y_2)\$ and our third point have co-ordinates \$(x_3, y_3)\$.

If the three points are collinear, then point three will lie on the line formed by joining points one and two. In other words, \$x_3\$, when plugged into the equation formed by the line joining points 1 and 2, gives \$y_3\$.

"But what's the line between point 1 and 2?" I hear you ask. Well, we use the good old "point-graident" method to find the line's equation:

$$
y - y_1 = m(x - x_1), m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}\\
y - y_1 = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}(x - x_1)
$$

Now, we add \$y_1\$ to both sides to get an equation where plugging in an `x` value gives a single `y` value:

$$
y = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}(x - x_1) + y_1
$$

Substituting \$x\$ for \$x_3\$ and \$y\$ for \$y_3\$ gives an equality that determines if three points are collinear.

Alright, time for the code (as explained by Kevin).

```
-                     "[x2-x1, y2-y1]"\
 V                    "pop and store it in variable `Y`"\
  ¹-                  "[x3-x1, y3-y1]"\
    н                 "Pop and leave only x3-x1"\
     Yн_i             "If x2-x1 from variable `Y` == 0:"\
         _            " Check if the x3-x1 at the top == 0"\
        ë             "Else:"\
         Y`s/         " Divide (y2-y1) by (x2-x1) from variable `Y`"\
             *        " Multiply it by the x3-x1 at the top"\
              ¹θ+     " Add x1"\
                 Q    " Check [x3 == this value, y3 == this value] with the implicit third input"\
                  θ   " And only keep the last one: y3 == this value"\
```

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I accidentally left the `X0Q` from a previous explanation. But still, yes, it should be `_` instead.

Comment: I still have to verify all test cases (I'll try to write a test suite in a bit), but I think [this 21 byter](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fN@zQTt0LeyMv7I3PjD@8OjKhWF/r0M5zO7QDz@34/z/axMxAx8jYzDiWK9rQ0MgcyLY0ArJ1DY2NTXSMjCxMYwE) should work without changing your formula.

Comment: [Here the same 21 byter with comments.](https://tio.run/##bVJPT8IwHL3zKV44gbLINkQl4WDUgwcTvZgQWKCwkv1CYctWkH0mvwAevOid8I1mWyBsst@pbfr@9L2GCRsTzzILZVPtrx1rbTeQOlZqe9VBBe@l96IwAlv4SGQYc5AELbBiMbGx4Bj1RhqJny@rVMLdS7hHCTW77/OLrwcNwdmKI1yIFAZ6gKC3@x5SEfI8hXkApnE4LxhCt4tm5wjVMywg8RDwyQw0hQz4XgdMmo1UPjQ6B/79LOo@iYQXyHuj5CpH/kgr8jlqJtY6xilqxmf93GieRc/FieVlKSRFKgaVt6IoM/ofrTrYbi4P@Hvfxym@/LzlM1AF6ffKgBLlTCy57qp44uGDZGBEaR4JmpB2QLGv/kG0lGUS2G72JlSjpssZ55FhECyR6oh3zmSqgyzrt9rNhuO2Xa/St23nRq3vHLW2bNdtNRzn9tr7Aw)

Comment: [Here a test suite for all test cases.](https://tio.run/##XY@9SkNBEIVf5ZJOncX5278qz2AjhOuSKFikEgwIKWytxbcQIXWaNDd9yDP4Ite5e6MQm53lmzOHc55W9w/Lx/5lPZ00328fzWS6Xuzfn7vP3t12G3fczY67@XK@/5otVteX3eawvbo5bPtXuLjr27YloAItA9srIMXGGSMEwpFixTZO/E@MVV2H/Kqdhzjy4XUEMnINdi9BBgviaP/MVSCiwJx8VTHHRAETg6qg4OBBTBFz9gySY0jeVxYl5GhhFJFQ2a6b/6X0rBSeNjVkTBkc02DlohdwVFt4SmC7MXFQQgsq6rOGYESjz3ZnIMUwmLpgxHoZkSSplPID) :) PS: I would make my explanation a bit prettier in your answer with actual comments, haha. ;) I only used `"..."\ ` in the 05AB1E code because that's the only way I know to add comments inside a program

Comment: @KevinCruijssen https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6467/78850

Comment: Oh, thank you! :) Tbh, I enjoy golfing other people's answers as much as writing answer myself. Glad I could help, and thanks for the bounty!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No worries. It seems only fair given the amount of times I've had to write "_-x bytes thanks to @Kevin_"!  ;P

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 39 bytes

```cs
(a,A,b,B,c,C)=>(b-a)/(B-A)==(c-a)/(C-A)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFNS8NAEIbP5lcMwUMWNrjfu7Gm0hY8eRQ8iIckpjRQUmhapZT89jqTKLXiQZiwM8@@82aSqbq06prTw76t7t42@3Jdc/jvWW426yksIT8lBZ/xks95xRcsnyZlWrCbZJ7OWJ4n1VAssDhNoui92MKu7nYd5NDWHy@vcIyuEskBQw2hMRj/BaWgZ8Ri4HR8XZzlP9hZf@ltLuHYoQaYWg5efOMUBXq0MI6odmQqlac8U6TQ2mChgh37fciQKok@qbeaFDSLlYFAGM2U8kE6EdDAGC20oO9R0ossszRi5l2wlpjXLvNkYISQwoxDOiMFjaCNzYxzeOltRu9FELzDoVOHhCZGooMOLOrxxy8327qoVpDQBnBhMMMNcphzqDgsGDTtuBcW4UKet82ufmzaOrmOj4OY9RyOCTWM2dDUQzrFfPmH3T3ET9v9bnWI4Rbih2Ld1YeY9TGbRP3pEw)

Comment: This is interesting.  I notice that it only works if you declare the input variables as ```double```s, otherwise it gives a divide-by-zero error when ```A``` equals ```B``` or ```C```.  So I'm wondering whether the variable declaration needs to be included in the byte count...?

Comment: The requirement for ```double```s is obviously removed by [rearranging like this](https://tio.run/##dZFNa4NAEIbP9VcM0oNbVtjvXZuakgRy6rHQQ@nBiCGBkICalhD87XZGW9KUFkadeXbmdfQtm7Rstv3yuC8ftvuWw7@31eGwm8Ia8j4p@Iyv@JyXfMHyabJKC3aXLNIZy/OkHIo5Fv0kit6LGtqqaRvIYV99vL7BObpJJAcMNYTGYPwXlIKuEYuB0@Pr4NL@g136r7XNNRwn1ABTy8GLb5xigx4ljCOqHYlK5SnPFHVobbBQwY7zPmRIlUSd1FtNHbSLlYFAGMWU8kE6EVDAGC20oO9R0osss7Ri5l2wlpjXLvMkYISQwoxLOiMFraCNzYxzeOhtRu9FELzDpVOHhDZGooMOLOrwx68PdVWUG0jIATQMZugghzmHksOCoaWjLyxCQ17qbVs9bfdVchufh2bWcTgnNDBmw1AH6RTz9R9yjxA/18d2c4rhHuJlsWuqU8y6mE2irv8E)...

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 45 bytes

```
{print!($2*$3+$4*$5+$6*$1-$1*$4-$2*$5-$3*$6)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5NSkQxEIT3c4oWeqFvCPR/JxuXnsALzEJQFJFxREQ8@7PfLIYI0lmkvkq66vD5vK7fb8en19PVNcqCukdb0PcYC3JDXtDaxr2hLhg3P@tuBa6RGq1pt3B//Dg9fu0umGk7/xgKtuG7w8v7wwXT2Zpwc0g6G41B/yyyKENDgVmybqM@sqqBSPf5Ycs@oAkXTK@SXIWc@8ZpzhLJzkFdwExJqZoLJ43h1XZkdPciqTGyNhgRk8kcFMZUVdR8WARY@qjkkj2DoUXp6lxau/Yp@Rc)

Near-identical to Rich Farmbrough's Perl answer, but the syntax seemed better-suited to AWK than Perl.  Thanks Rich!

Comment: I extracted some common factors, and saved a few bytes.

Comment: @Rich Farmbrough Well done!  That would bring the AWK clone to [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY5NSkQxEIT3c4oIWcxTAv3fycalJ/ACsxAURWQcERHP/qw3iyGCdBbVXyWpOnw@r@v32/Hp9XS1r3K9r9qqLzfVIL1VhgxIblWX5WfdrYUxglFMuy33x4/T49fugpm284@hxTZ8d3h5f7hgOlsTbl6Szkbjon8@soChoYVZEmrgIataEek@X2zZR2nCgOkoySjk3DdOc5ZIdg7qUsyUlNBcOGkMR9uR0d1BUmMkfjAiJpM5KIwJVdR8WESx9IFkrD2DSwvs6Ixdu/Yp@Rc), although copying you a second time seems sneaky so I'm leaving it here in the comment section...

Comment: Shaping the code like this will save 3 more bytes: `$0=!($2*($3-$5)+$4*($5-$1)+$6*($1-$3))e`

Comment: @PedroMaimere - Nice golfing!  I didn't think of redefining ```$0``` and using a dummy variable to force output...  You should post this yourself!  It's nice to have some more AWK competition!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen don't worry. It's a common technique. In fact, it is also described in [Tips for golfing in Awk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13014/tips-for-golfing-in-awk).

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＮζ⁼×⁻ηＮ⁻θＮ×⁻ηＮ⁻θζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYu9CsIwGEV3nyJjAhW@/Dd0dnBQHHyBWAoJpK1NGoe@fAy4lE6O555ze2djP9tQynV65/Wex9cQ8UK6057dgbfKj@inFV@WbEPCTz8OCd/8lBN2Ddq3hDToJ5ajqObf41Zr0pXCmG6pgpYhIThwAEQZ1WCMZIgbrVop66K5MpoCEgAUBCvnT/gC) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as six integers and outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for collinear, nothing if not. Uses @SurculoseSputum's original formula. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ                      Input `a`
  Ｎη                    Input `A`
    Ｎζ                  Input `b`
         η              `A`
        ⁻               Minus
          Ｎ             Input `B`
       ×                Multiplied by
            θ           `a`
           ⁻            Minus
             Ｎ          Input `c`
      ⁼                 Equals
                η       `A`
               ⁻        Minus
                 Ｎ      Input `C`
              ×         Multiplied by
                   θ    `a`
                  ⁻     Minus
                    ζ   `b`
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Excel], 37 bytes

```
=0=MDETERM(A1:C3+{0,0,1;0,0,1;0,0,1})
```

Example: [image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Google Sheets], 27 bytes

```
=0=MDETERM({A1:B3,{1;1;1}})
```

[Try it online!](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OhwBPJXakq9GbDboNJlvE5xGybciybHrXvqCyAxtNXw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>35</s>62 bytes

```perl
sub d{($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f)=@_;$b*($c-$e)+$d*($e-$a)+$f*($a-$c)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDbagIxEIbv9ylSmYukJjXnA7baqz5BL4WyuisKIuKBUsRnt5PVtru0CM3Nzvz7/TN/sqm3K3d@XyxXNaGPI3YsCJ7lnNABpWI8qfrsoT/@Z8UG1znXURWhoDkYDpaD4@A5BPaD5LPZLtd70qOgGBEj8lKudvXH3WTdG35Rp6@ixl/klvl1e9gv/jKfilNRnHeHKamOFEoOUw4zDhWHmsOcPT2/DWF6T2EmoGZ9qLCsBZRYzrEsBczY6YwTqOJEMU6o5kTnr@HEtFYXvwAlUZA3EZxhW3fvAPIbbAPCcRJkGxHoMd011uNqbbxpYigdcpf0hTbGYquj61hEiIkToZVrqOAwmlCq2eBUxCZE2UmidYjKy4g5rDXSyIZVWgWZkkPVpOCjcxc1GJ9CfhErpZJWd5Z7q2QOaaxL1vvssMGlnAilGHzzJsKjlm@GmokmttN8Ag)

I've put the wrapping on as explained in the comments, and golfed the original "guts"  down by picking out some common factors

$b*($c-$e)+$d*($e-$a)+$f*($a-$c)

(--First attempt --)

```perl
$b*$c+$d*$e+$f*$a-$a*$d-$c*$f-$e*$b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDbasJAEIbv8xRTmYsk7tY97wZb7VWfoJdCiSaiYEU8UKT47HY22jahRejCkJ0/38z8O5t6u7Ln98VyVUP6MMo@EqCznEM6SFM@nlT97L4//uctG1z7XFtV9R5SVAw1Q8PQMnQMffYDxbPZLtd76KUoM@AjeC5Xu/p4N1n3hl/U6etS0y@4VfyyPewXfxWfklOS7A5TiJZih7cjOSsZ4JRiRlFR1BTzDB7h6XV4xmmOsz5WOdZ9nOdYcixzrDjOcpxzrHOcnqnpOZUMZMYgVQxU/GoGuuUm@QVIQYK4iVAP01pHBxDfYBvgloEXbYRTje6OMY5GK@10Y0MqH7NCXWitDaUq2E4J96FgwJW0DeUtWeNSNhOsDJT4IDpOlPJBOhHIhzFaaNGwUkkvisKSqgvvgrUX1WtX@LgRI4QURnWGOyNFNKmNLYxzscJ4W0RHJAXvmp1wR1p8GWk66NB28wk)

- Not sure if this follows the rules (where are they?) for header and footer, as much trying out "tio" as anything.
- This takes the test text as per the question and outputs the exact same text!  In other words it's equivalent to while(<>){print}, provided you feed it a crib sheet.  If you remove (or change) the answers from the input, it will supply them.

Comment: I don't know Perl very well, but this seems like it takes input as predefined variables, which is [not permitted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) since it would make this a snippet rather than a program/function. You can fix this e.g. by turning it into a full program (taking input from STDIN or other allowed in the linked meta) or including the full function header (`sub det` etc) in the code. Btw, welcome back to Code Golf!

Comment: Nice, but I think that the syntax works even better in AWK (which automatically divides the variables up in exactly the way you've used)...  so I've [stolen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206838/are-they-collinear/206999#206999) the approach, with acknowledgment.

Comment: The [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/76162) for submissions are either full programs or functions, of which this is neither. Valid input/output formats are listed [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/76162). Usually people use headers to assign anonymous functions which are then called in the footer, possibly with some formatting of the input

Comment: Your actual submission be [this](https://tio.run/##lZDbasJAEIbv8xRTmYsk7tY97wZb7VWfoJdCiSaiYEU8UKT47HY22jahRejCkJ0/38z8O5t6u7Ln98VyVUP6MMo@EqCznEM6SFM@nlT97L4//uctG1z7XFtV9R5SVAw1Q8PQMnQMffYDxbPZLtd76KUoM@AjeC5Xu/p4N1n3hl/U6etS0y@4VfyyPewXfxWfklOSnHeHKURPscXbkayVDHBKMaOoKGqKeQaP8PQ6THCa46yPVY51H@c5lhzLHCuOsxznHOscp8npTG1TyUBmDFLFQMWvZqBbfpJfgBQkiJsI9TCthXQA8Q22AW4ZeNFGONXo7hjjaLTSTjc2pPIxK9SF1tpQqoLtlHAfCgZcSdtQ3pI1LmUzwcpAiQ@i40QpH6QTgXwYo4UWDSuV9KIoLKm68C5Ye1G9doWPGzFCSGFUZ7gzUkST2tjCOBcrjLdFdERS8K7ZCXekxZeRpoMObTef) at 83 bytes (though this is obviously golfable)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
EẊoF/z-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/Xhrq58N/0q3f///0dHG@oYxupEG@kYAUljHePYWAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
v-ÞḊ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#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)

Outputs `0` for truthy and any other integer for falsy. Port of fireflame241's Jelly answer. Add `¬` at the end to get `1` for truthy and `0` for falsy.